# Push back to a static vector< pair<string, double[9]> > myVector;

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, double, std-pair

I want to store an amount of information which will contain 1 string, and 9 doubles. This info will belong to one "item" so I want to sort by the name, and thus I have decided to put this into a vector of pairs, with the first section of the pair being the name and the second an array of doubles. So I can sort it easily and access them with ease as well.

I have a C++ class with a static private data member "myVector"

The code looks like this:

```
class MyClass : public OtherClass{
private:
    static vector< pair<string, double[9]> > myVector;
public:
    MyClass(void);
    ~MyClass(void);
};
vector< pair<string, double[9]> > MyClass::myVector;
```

The issue is that in the .cpp of this class, when I try to do the following:

```
myVector.push_back(make_pair(sName, dNumericData));
```

where sName is a variable of type string, and dNumericData is a variable of type double array size 9, I get an error saying:

```
2   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=std::pair<std::string, double [9]>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, double [9]>>]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>, double *>)
        object type is: std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double [9]>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string, double [9]>>>
```

Any ideas of how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Are you able to use C++11 and std::array<>?

Comment: I am free to use c++11 or 12, as far as using std::array<>, do you mean in place of the vector? or pair, or double[]?

Comment: Thanks John, this seems to be the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dNumericData` decays to a pointer, so the argument types do not match. You can use `std::array<>` for both the pair type and `dNumericData` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try to implement that

Comment: I gave my attempt at is, I cant get the formatting correct in a comment so I put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/YC4nSYj9 But I get a bunch of linker errors I think the issue lies within the fact that the array is const, and I can no longer edit it afterwards?

Comment: could you paste in what you used to test? Maybe I'm missing something as far as an include etc? I've included <array>

Comment: @user3483187 Do you mind telling me what these linker errors say? [When I run your code it compiles perfectly.](http://rextester.com/MGQV86374)

Comment: @user3483187 I going to assume you're using a header file. You're getting multiple-definition errors because you didn't use `extern`. Please put `extern` before the type of the vector in the header file. Then, in the cpp file, you can define it.

Comment: Yes, I am using a header file. My vector already has static infront of it, how can I place extern as well?

Comment: @user3483187 It would be `extern static vector<...`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I get a couple of errors: Error 1 error C2159: more than one storage class specified and the ide also says that "Error: invalid storage class for a class member"

Comment: @user3483187 I'm going to try and replicate what you're doing on my compiler so I can figure out what's wrong. brb :)

Comment: would it help if I zip up my source files? This isn't anything that I need protected. I could send you a dropbox url

Comment: @user3483187 No need but thank you. Your code is small enough. Here's an idea. Instead of using `extern`, wrap your class and the initialization of the vector within an anonymous namespace. [Like this](http://rextester.com/OTKR81672)

Comment: One clarification, my class definition is in a .h file but I am trying to access the variable in a completely other class that inherits the MyClass publicly. Would creating the name space still allow me to do that?

Comment: @user3483187 Is there another file that is including the header file that this code is associated with?

Comment: `extern static` is an error... what was that supposed to do?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sorry about that. I thought that would compile.

Comment: The way I have it written is a "Menu" class is called in main, which then publicly inherits this "Data" class.

so basically main instantiates menu, which in menu.h it includes data.h which is where the definition for all of this is written

Comment: @user3483187 Okay, nevermind about the `namespace {}` for now (please remove it). I got it to work by moving the definition `vector<pair<string, array<double,9>> MyClass::myVector;` to the `.cpp` file. Does it work for you?

Comment: YES! that compiles perfectly. Just a quick question, is it an acceptable practice to initialize the data member outside the .h? I think it should be fine, but regardless this worked perfectly. Thank you, sincerely, for your continual help!

Comment: @user3483187 No, it is actually improper to define it in the `.h` file. Doing it in the `.cpp` file is correct. :)

Comment: :)
doing it in the .h file was the example my professor showed us :O, what you said makes total sense

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a struct or class instead of using std::pair:

```
struct MyStuff {
  string name;
  array<double, 9> values; // use float unless you need so much precision

  MyStuff(string name_, array<double, 9> values_) : name(name_), values(values_) {}
};

vector<MyStuff> v;
v.emplace_back(MyStuff("Jenny", {{8,6,7,5,3,0,9}}));
```

Comment: One of the factors that I chose a pair was because I can sort the vector with .sort, If I'm not mistaken if its a struct I would need to overload the < operator to be able to sort it in that method so I tried to avoid structs. Can I sort it?

Comment: You're right, you'll need to define operator<.  But that's OK, I think the benefits are worth it (e.g. not having the members be called "first" and "second", you can make the code more self-descriptive).

Comment: I actually had the same issue before, I managed to avoid overloading the operator by using a pair. The reason why I avoid it is.. well I don't know how to do it properly. I guess I may have to look into this. hmm it doesn't seem to be as complicated as I had thought. this may pan out

Comment: Is this legal? `vector` elements have to be copyable, and `std::array` is not copyable.